# Best practice of using restkit and core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, restkit

I am building an application that is constantly speaking to a `webservice`. So posting and getting data all the time. But all the data that I post and get should also be saved on the phone.

**Problem 1**

When I was looking through the examples. I saw that they are loading all the data in the `appDelegate`. For loading in small amount of data this is probably the best way to do it. But in my case, is it still the best way or should I do this on `ViewController Level`.

**Problem 2**

When I started the application I checked *use core data* this generated a lot of code for me in the `appDelegate`. But in this case I can't get to my `managedObjectContext` on `viewController` Level, right?

My question is now, what is the best way to get this properly done?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem 1
>
> When I was looking through the examples. I saw that they are loading all the data in the appDelegate. For loading in small amount of data this is probably the best way to do it. But in my case, is it still the best way or should I do this on ViewController Level.

The use of an appDelegate for that is typical of sample code.

How to best deal with that depends strictly on your app. Encapsulating data transfer into your view controller is certainly a step forward compared to using the app delegate. But, depending on your app, you might also devise a more specific data load controller to encapsulate all the relevant behavior. Indeed, I think the latter option works best even for relatively simple projects.

> Problem 2
>
> When I started the application I checked use core data this generated a lot of code for me in the appDelegate. But in this case I can't get to my managedObjectContext on viewController Level, right?

If you look into the appDelegate.h file you should find properties for accessing core data from your controllers:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

You could use that to access the managed object context through `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` or you could factor that code out of the app delegate into your own model manager class. Again, this is strictly depending on your app. There are apps that use only 1 managed object contexts, apps that deal with more, etc. If your app does a very basic use of core data, you could leave this as it is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It helped me alot! But now I'm experimenting with RestKit, but I got the following problem, hope you can help me also over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196908/restkit-route-error

Comment: Glad to have helped on this, but I have no idea about the other issue you are having, I am sorry...